# Cast Into Difficult Position

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I have this question about [this](http://sports.yahoo.com/news/madison-bumgarner-shuts-out-royals-as-giants-move-to-brink-of-championship-032111102.html):

> For the second time in the series, Bumgarner outpitched James Shields, although this time Shields put up something of a fight. A pair of early runs, scrounged together with the typical plodding, base-at-a-time attack of the Giants, were all Bumgarner required.  Nearing the end of October (and, likely, his time with the Royals), Shields had been ***cast into the difficult position*** of tending to mechanical and strategic adjustments between starts. His regular season ERA – 3.77 – had grown to 7.11 in four postseason starts. Opposing hitters had batted .337. The Royals had, often enough, won around him, in spite of him, a reality that contrasted with the notion that held Shields as the club’s go-to starter.

What is "*cast into a position*"?  Is it similar to theater casting of actors?

Answer (score 1):

*Cast* has many meanings. In this context, *cast* essentially means *throw*. OED provides this [definition](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28533?rskey=KchrGw&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> **cast**: The simple action: To throw
>
> To project (anything) with a force of the nature of a jerk, from the hand, the arms, a vessel, or the like; to throw (which is now the ordinary equivalent); to fling, hurl, pitch, toss.

These phrases would have nearly the same meaning:

*Shields had been **thrown into** the difficult position...*

*Shields had been **thrust into** the difficult position...*

*Shields had been **forced into** the difficult position...*